# how to close the webview flutter

Tags: flutter

i wont it to work until it reach a somepoint .  So how can i close the webview and go to another widget after i got  the request.url.startsWith('https://youtube.com/')

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class WebPageAuth extends StatefulWidget {
final url;

WebPageAuth(this.url);

@override
_WebPageAuthState createState() => _WebPageAuthState(this.url);
}

class _WebPageAuthState extends State<WebPageAuth> {
var _url;
 final _key = UniqueKey();
_WebPageAuthState(this._url);
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
 body: Column(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: WebView(
            key: _key,
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
            initialUrl: _url,
            navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {
              request.url.startsWith('https://youtube.com/');
              var Value =  request.url ;
              return NavigationDecision.navigate;
            }),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
}
}
```

Comment: You can try to add button on screen with WebView and close screen by it.

Comment: what i want is closing it after it reach a known URL

Answer (score 3):

You can check the URL then change the state:

```
navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {
    if (request.url == 'http://destination.com/') {
       setState(() {
           _dstReached = true;           
       });
       // do not navigate
       return NavigationDecision.prevent;
    }

    return NavigationDecision.navigate;
}
```

In the build function, you can check the state and build the next widget like this:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        // display Text widget if destination was reached
        // otherwise use WebView
        body: _dstReached ? Text('next step') : Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: WebView(...
```